# How to setup workspace folder as root folder in VS Code to run python pipelines

Tags: visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I have a folder structure in VS code as follows:

```
project
├── functions/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_module.py
└── pipeline/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── run_code.py
└── setup.py/
```

[folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSdgi.png)

inside the run_code.py, it imports function `from functions.my_module import new_func`.
however, it is giving `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I tried below points:

1. Added below in settings.json

```
    "python.analysis.extraPaths`":["${workspaceFolder}"],
    "launch": {     "configurations": [],
    "compounds": [],
    "cwd": "${`workspace Folder\`}"
    },
```

2. tested with adding `sys.path.append()` at top and it worked. But this is not a standard way
3. Added **init**.py in each subfolders and it is not working

Kindly help.